# Dynamically size text and buttons to stay within container

Tags: html, css

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Benne', serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

:root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#question-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 75% auto;
}

#question {
    font-size: 1.5rem; /* fallback */
    /*font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);*/
    font-size: 75%;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
}

.container {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    background: ghostwhite;
}

.container:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0.813em solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: -0.406em;
    margin-right: -0.812em;
}

.btn-grid {
    /*display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    height: 20%;*/
    display: flex;
    height: 20%;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: black; /*Button Color*/
    color: white;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #627295;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    margin-right: 1vw;
}

.btn:active {
    /*on Click*/
    -ms-transform: translateY(4px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px); /*Move down*/
    border-color: black; /*disappears*/
}

.start-btn,
.next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 1.5rem, 2rem);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.no-btn:after {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: .5em;
    content: "\27F5"
}

.yes-btn:after {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: .5em;
    content: "\27F6"
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'chat_bubble character_image'
        'button_menu character_image';
    grid-template-columns: 5fr 1fr;
    place-items: center;
}

#chat_bubble {
    grid-area: chat_bubble;
    width: 70vw;
    height: 70vh;
    padding-left: 2vw;
    padding-right: 2vw;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

#character_image {
    grid-area: character_image;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}
#character_image > img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

#char_1 {
    display: inline-block;
}

#button_menu {
    grid-area: button_menu;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    gap: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    #main {
        grid-template-areas:
            'chat_bubble chat_bubble'
            'button_menu character_image';
        grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
    }

    #character_image > img {
        height: 100px;
        max-width: unset;
    }
    
    .container:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        top: unset;
        right: unset;
        left: 75%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 0.813em solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        margin-left: -0.406em;
        margin-bottom: -0.812em;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="chat_bubble" class="container">
        <div id="email-container" class="hide">
            <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            <button id="submit-email-btn" class="btn btn-white">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
            <div id="question" class="question-text">Question</div>
            <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn btn-grid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="chart" class="hide"></div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="character_image">
      <img id="char_1" src="https://i.imgur.com/7eYWqqo.png" alt=""></img>
    </div>
    <div id="button_menu">
        <button id="dark-mode" class="btn">Dark</button>
        <button id="restart" class="btn">Restart</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a container div which contains a chat bubble which contains a question-container which contains some text and buttons. I need the text and buttons to dynamically get smaller depending on the size of the screen to fit inside the chat_bubble, but right now the buttons and text expand outside of the container. I know part of this has to do with the clamp function in my font-size, but I'm not sure how to fix it or figure out the correct values.

This is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

Someone explained to me that if I set the font-size to vw instead of rem I can get it to be more responsive which I found to be true, but what I need is for the text to fill up the top 75% of the chat_bubble container, and for the buttons to fill the bottom 25%, so that even if there's a lot of text there's no risk of formatting issues.

I tried creating a div with a grid and having the question and answer-buttons within that grid, but I must not know what I'm doing because all I've created is a black rectangle that isn't even within the confines of the parent div. Here is the relevant HTML and all of my CSS>

Comment: If you use `rem` you must set a font-size on `:root` so all `rem` lengths can have a reference. Try: `:root {font-size:16px}` and remove `font-size: 75%` from `#question` if you want that text to be dynamic as well.

Comment: Thanks but I update my codepen with your suggestions and the text and buttons still extend past the bottom of the screen when you resize it. And for some reason trying to create a grid just makes a long black rectangle.

Comment: can u add screenshot how it should look like (expected) ?

Comment: So basically I'm just trying to have a grid with two rows, the top row 75% of chat_bubble with the question container, and the bottom row 25% with the answer buttons. The text and buttons should expand to fill all of the container except for a 2vh/2vw padding top, bottom, left, and right. Center aligned vertically and horizontally.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/o623x8K

Comment: With a maximum font size of 12vh.